# Работа с пользовательским DataTable.Columns

Tags: c#

Имеется свой DataColumn:

```
public class MyDataColumn : DataColumn
{
...
  public MyDataColumn(bool b, string s)
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

Также имеется свой DataTable:

```
public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
  public MyDataTable(string path)
  {
    ...
  }
  public void Save()
  {
    this.WriteXml(path, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
  }
  public void Load()
  {
    this.ReadXml(path);
  }
}
```

Запускаю все нормально работает пока создаю таблицу myDataTable с помощью кода, создаются столбцы MyDataColumn и строки. Сохраняется в XML-файл и закрывается приложение. После открытия и соответственно загрузки данных в myDataTable из XML-файла перестает работать свойство myDataTable.Columns. Например, в таком коде:

```
foreach (MyDataColumn col in myDataTable.Columns)
{ ... }
```

или

```
MyDataColumn myCol = myDataTable.Columns[1];
```

Приложение вылетает. После недолгих мучений выяснил, что вылет из за ошибки типа: Невозможно привести DataColumn к типу MyDataColumn. Поиск решения не дает, да и не знаю как правильно ввести запрос в гугле. Помогите пожалуйста решением или дайте ссылку, если подобная тема уже обсуждалась...

Comment: А Вы уверены, что `myDataTable.Columns[1]` это `MyDataColumn`?

Comment: до перезапуска приложение именно так и есть, а вот после - уже как раз таки нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> После открытия и соответственно загрузки данных в myDataTable из XML-файла перестает работать свойство myDataTable.Columns

Естественно. Потому что DataTable ничего не знает про ваш тип колонок, и когда вы восстанавливаете данные из файла, создаются колонки типа DataColumn. Какого-то очевидного решения тут нет.

Однако у меня есть ощущение, что вы решаете задачу не тем способом. Честно говоря, первый раз встречаю, чтобы люди наследовали DataTable/DataColumn. Зачем вам это нужно? Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Пытался сделать дополнительные свойства и методы для DataColumn и DataTable, обеспечивающих быстрый доступ к ExtendedProperties и некоторые методы. Так как у меня несколько однотипных таблиц, которые можно было бы легко визуализировать в приложении. Но видимо придется все переделывать... Решения похоже действительно нет...

Comment: Переделал проект удалив наследия. Теперь достигнут нужный результат. Всем спасибо

Comment: @krupennikov: вообще, следует предпочитать композицию наследованию, если возможно.

Comment: @krupennikov @VladD да, в таком случае лучше сделать обертку над таблицей, и через обертку предоставить "быстрый" доступ к нужным свойствам.

Comment: @andreycha, именно так я и сделал: Просто обертку без наследия